# Avoid OutOfMemoryError in android

Tags: android

Loading images onto ImageView in xml takes more memory?

I Have an Activity with around 7 imageviews(just like the app tray in any android phone.)

I am loading the images for each of the imageviews in the xml. Does this cause OutOfMemoryError?

Is there a way to recycle these?

Comment: Memory out of bound ..it might depends on the size of the image

Comment: are you setting image from server?

Comment: Is it possible to attach the drawables to the imageView at run time and recycle them anytime not needed?
All the images are in my drwable folders.

Comment: show your stack and code. so you can get answer quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to attach `drawable` images to `ImageView` and you can remove them when you need.

```
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
                or    
imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

It does not cause any out of memory issue. [Link to Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem when i was loading Images. Sometimes this error can only be seen in Android emulator, sometimes this crashes the app in the mobile device too.

I solved this problem by following two steps:

1. Re-size the image if the resolution is too high.
2. Not having too many image objects open at the same time.

   You can help the garbage collector out too, by assigning the image object to NULL when it is no longer necessary.

Unless necessary i would prevent opening too many images at the same time.

The factor by which you have to re-size, will depend on the actual size of the image.

Comment: Assigning to null gives me nightmares. Graphic objects have a recycle or destroy method, use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Few Tips to address memory issues in Android:

1). Never use local variables to store large data / bitmaps specially in loops, As it will create un-necessary objects. I prefer class/instance variables in such situations. Try not to persist data unless it is required.

2). Avoid making calls to View.findViewById(..) wherever you can. Romain Guy has clearly stated in [Google I/O 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) that this method is costly (takes some KBs of memory to run), so call this method smartly like using ViewHolder which will consume less memory.

3) Use String pool effectively and use StringBuilder/StringBuffer when you are doing heavy operations with strings. Make sure that you are aware when you have to use StringBuffer as it is synchronized and again costly in comparison to StringBuilder.